# Why did David kill someone he seemed to care for?

Tags: plot-explanation, alien-covenant

After watching Alien Covenant, it was not clear as to why David would kill Elizabeth?  David was obviously a nutter, yes, but in my interpretation of the film he really cared for Elizabeth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David probably killed Elizabeth because he had no other test subjects available. His treatment of Holloway, Oram, and Daniels proves that he has absolutely no regard for human life.